# How to find Name of class<?> used in list

Tags: java, generic-list

I have one Struts2 Action class

there is getters/setters of `java.util.List list;`

but I don't know about its generic type `List<?> list;`

I have code here :

```
 public class Test
 {
    private List list;

    public List getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public String execute()throws Exception
    {
       for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
       {
           //how can print here list
           // in this situation i have List<Detail> list
           // filed is id ,username,password
           // but i want to print dynamically get class name and then filed name and then print list
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an answer posted before, you can use the "for each" loop:

```
for(Object element : list) {
 System.out.println("Class of the element: " + element.getClass());
 // If you want to do some validation, you can use the instanceof modifier
 if(element instanceof EmployeeBean) {
  System.out.println("This is a employee");
  // Then I cast the element and proceed with operations
  Employee e = (Employee) element;
  double totalSalary = e.getSalary() + e.getBonification();
 }
}
```

If you want to do it with "for while" loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
 System.out.println("Element class: " + list.get(i).getClass());
 if (list.get(i) instanceof EmployeeBean) {
  EmployeeBean e = (EmployeeBean) list.get(i);
  // keep with operations
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a start you should make the method a generics method rather than just using List. Something along the following lines

```
public void parseList(List<T> list) {
    for (T list_entry : list) {
        System.out.println("File name: "+list_entry.getClass());
        System.out.println("List entry: " + list_entry);
    }
}
```

I realise this doesn't help so much with actually printing the file name, but it does help you to get the runtime class of the object coming out of the list.

Answer (score 0):

The `List` is a generic class. But you should know what type you use with this generic class. If you use the `List` (your case) in the `for` loop then you should write

```
for(Object o: list){
  if (o instanceof Detail){ //you can omit it if you 100% sure it is the Detail
   Detail d = (Detail)o; //explicitly typecast 
   //print it here 
  }
}
```

but the better to specialize the `list` property to be 100% sure it is the `Detail`s list

```
private List<Detail> list;

public List<Detail> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<Detail> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

then you can use

```
for(Detail d: list){
   //print it here 
}
```